# ITK: Could not create IO object

Tags: c++, image, itk

I am trying to calculate the gradient of an image. I tried [this code](http://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/ImageGradient/ComputeGradientMagnitudeRecursiveGaussian/Documentation.html) on the sample image given (Gourds6.png).

I used `cmake .` to create the CMakeFiles and then `make`. Everything works fine and the executable file is created. Now when I run the code using command `./computeGradient Gourds6.png out.png 1.5`, it complains that:

```
Error: 
itk::ImageFileWriterException (0x1446b40)
Location: "void itk::ImageFileWriter<TInputImage>::Write() [with TInputImage = itk::Image<float, 2u>]" 
File: /usr/local/include/ITK-4.3/itkImageFileWriter.hxx
Line: 152
Description:  Could not create IO object for file out.png
  Tried to create one of the following:
  You probably failed to set a file suffix, or
    set the suffix to an unsupported type.
```

I haven't done any change to this code. It should work. I don't know what is wrong with it :( Do you have any idea?

Also, why don't we need to update the reader to read the image? Why do we only update the writer?

I appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pixel type of the output file in [this example of ITK](http://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/ImageGradient/ComputeGradientMagnitudeRecursiveGaussian/Documentation.html) is `float`. And writing an image of `float` as a PNG image is not possible.

A list of supported files formats and corresponding data types is given on [the wiki of ITK](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/File_Formats).

To save this image of `float`, here are formats that are expected to work :

- Analyze (.img)
- DICOM (.dic : failed on my PC)
- GIPL (.gipl)
- MetaImage (mhd) (out.mhd+out.raw)
- Nrrd (.nhdr, .nrrd)
- Stimulate (.spr)
- VTK (.vtk)

The VTK file format works well and may be opened by the paraview software.

To use a PNG format, the image should be casted to `unsigned char` type. It may be performed by the [`CastImageFilter()`](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1CastImageFilter.html). See this [example](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/ImageProcessing/CastImageFilter). Another solution is to use the [`RescaleIntensityImageFilter()`](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1RescaleIntensityImageFilter.html). See this [example](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/ImageProcessing/RescaleIntensityImageFilter).

[This question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768662/is-there-any-way-to-convert-an-eigenmatrix-back-to-itkimage/27786763#27786763) (which happens to be mine) explains how to convert a `float` image type to a ùnsigned char` image type and save it as PNG.

```
typedef itk::RescaleIntensityImageFilter< FloatImageType, UCharImageType > RescaleFilterType;
RescaleFilterType::Pointer rescaleFilter = RescaleFilterType::New();

rescaleFilter ->SetInput(importFilter->GetOutput());
rescaleFilter->SetOutputMinimum(0);
rescaleFilter->SetOutputMaximum(255);

typedef itk::ImageFileWriter<  UCharImageType  > WriterType;
WriterType::Pointer writer = WriterType::New();

writer->SetFileName( "output.png" );
writer->SetInput(rescaleFilter->GetOutput() );
writer->Update();
```

Finally, your last question : why do we only update the writer ? As the writer is updated, it will first check if its entries are up to date. If it is not the case, it will call `filter->Update()`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I had this idea of converting but then I thought, that code comes with that given sample image (which is in png format) so it should work!

Comment: ***DICOM (.dic : failed on my PC)*** The most common extension for dicom files is .dcm.